# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

tengo un problema de conexión con la base de datos y si alguien me podría ayudar me sería de mucha ayuda.

Al crear la conexión en la base de datos no me deja conectarla debido a este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He comprobado con el comando lsnrctl status en el cmd para ver si el listener era el problema, pero me pone que se ejecuto correctamente

[image]

Comment: Tu lsnrctl dice que hay una instancia orcl, y tú en la conexión usas xe. El error ORA-12505 dice "TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor" y pues tiene sentido, ¿no?